# Unable to connect iPhones after MAC address filtering to TP link router TL-WR840N

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iphone, mac-address

I enabled MAC address filtering on my TP link router TL-WR840N and I am unable to connect all other devices to it (Android TV, NVR, Android phones and MacBook). The only problem is I can't connect any iPhone to it. I have added Mac address of my iPhones in routers whitelist but still can't connect to the router. If I disable MAC address filtering I can connect easily with my iPhones.

Comment: Do you have the "private address" option on or off on your iPhones for your WiFi network? You can access the setting on your iPhone via Settings->WiFi and tapping the (i) button next to your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhones default to randomising their MAC address when connecting to WiFi, to prevent tracking.
You can disable this for your home network to enable such as MAC Address filtering.

Settings > WiFi > then click the (i) next to your home connection & disble Private WiFi Address…

[image]

This will then generate a privacy warning on the main page, which you can ignore for a home network.

[image]

Comment: Thanks brother it helped a lot and I was unable to find the solution online from a long time.